# Center remaining bootstrap columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a layout which will sometimes had the odd 1, 2 or 3 columns at the end like so:

[image]

I'm looking to write something that says if their are any remaining columns that don't complete a row then display in the middle, like so:

[image]

I understand this might be tricky as if there are 3 remaining items, it will have to change the column structure perhaps.

The items are brought in dynamically so it wouldn't help to apply the code once tot he layout...

This would also be useful if one of the containers only contained say, 2 items, which id like to display centred rather than left

I can't seem to find a nice way of doing this, I can't see anything on the bootstrap site.

Here's the code I'm playing with - I was hoping Bootstrap would have a class that I can add to the item that does this, but I cant seem to see anything

Is it even possible? Thanks for looking :)

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  display:block;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item">CENTER</div></div>
    <div class="col-3"><div class="item">CENTER</div></div>
  </div
</div
```

Comment: You might want to look into `offset-3` class. But i'm not sure how to apply it dynamicaly. Perharps bootstrap column are not the right tool here. Use flex instead.

Comment: justify-content-center to row https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: @Nicolas bootstrap is made up with flexbox

Comment: Ah thank you Temani -quite simple lol!! If you add this as an answer I will mark it correct!